# GetPixel,SetPixel and DrawImage does not work well for me

Tags: c#, graphics, bitmap

I was trying to create simple program that would perform some trivial operation with given image.
For some reason, it works only for the first time (when the app is launched):

//pseudo code

```
Bitmap im=Bitmap.FromFile("D:\\x.BMP");
Color [,] ColorArray=new [im.Width,im.Height];
private override voide OnPaint(EventArgs e)
{

  for(int X=0;X<im.Width;X++)
  {
      for(int Y=0;Y<im.Height;Y++)
      {
        ColorArray[X,Y]=im.GetPixel[X,Y];
      }

  }
  for(int X=0;X<im.Width;X++)
  {
      for(int Y=0;Y<im.Height;Y++)
      {
        Color c=ColorArray[X,Y];
        ...
        //some code that adds 100 to R,G,B
        im.SetPixel(X,Y,c);
      }

  }


  e.Graphics.DrawImage(im);
}
```

Comment: Are you resetting the `array` each time?

Comment: The pseudo code looks all right. How does it differ from the actual code?

Comment: As an aside, When I wanted to play with Image Processing on C#, I found the [Per Pixel Filters tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/csharpgraphicfilters11.aspx) by Christian Grauss to be pretty helpful.  Note that he recommends against `GetPixel`/`SetPixel` due to efficiency concerns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[EDIT]**

I have modified my sample code.  With the previous version, it could be hard to see the difference from one iteration to the next (especially with the bmp I was using for testing).  This one allows you to change color gradually by pressing 1, 2, or 3 on the Num Pad.  As others have mentioned, SetPixel/GetPixel is slow, so each KeyUp event does take some time to run.

This works fine for me.

Create a new Windows Forms project.  Drop this code in.  Make sure you have "x.bmp" available.  Each time you press 1, 2, or 3 on the number pad (you might need turn on Num Lock), the colors of the bitmap change slightly:

```
  public partial class Form1 : Form
  {
    Bitmap bm;
    Color [,] colors;

    public Form1()
    {
      bm = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromFile("x.bmp");
      colors = new Color[bm.Width, bm.Height];

      InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
      e.Graphics.DrawImage(bm,new Point(0,0));
    }

    private void Form1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
      //Change the colors a little bit on each KeyUp.
      //On NumPad1, change red.
      //On NumPad2, change green.
      //On NumPad3, change blue.
      //Mod with 256 to ensure a value between 0 and 255.
      int rInc = 0;
      int gInc = 0;
      int bInc = 0;

      switch (e.KeyCode)
      {
        case Keys.NumPad1:
          rInc = 20;
          break;
        case Keys.NumPad2:
          gInc = 20;
          break;
        case Keys.NumPad3:
          bInc = 20;
          break;
        default:
          break;
      }

      for (int x = 0; x < bm.Width; x++)
      {
        for (int y = 0; y < bm.Height; y++)
        {
          colors[x, y] = bm.GetPixel(x, y);
        }
      }

      for (int x = 0; x < bm.Width; x++)
      {
        for (int y = 0; y < bm.Height; y++)
        {
          Color c = colors[x, y];

          int r = (c.R + rInc) % 256;
          int g = (c.G + gInc) % 256;
          int b = (c.B + bInc) % 256;

          c = Color.FromArgb(255, r, g, b);
          bm.SetPixel(x, y, c);
        }
      }

      Invalidate();
    }

  }
```

It's not very sophisticated, but it does what you asked with real code that closely matches your pseudocode.

Answer (score 0):

You can improve your performance  when looping over pixels,  arrange the loops to access the  pixels in row order (x coordinates) in the inner loop. That best matches the image memory layout so it will improve CPU cache performance

```
for ( y = 0, y < bm.Height; y++)
{
    ...

    for ( x = 0, x < bm.Width; x++)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```